# SQLAlchemy two relationships in one table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

i have 3 tables: exchanges,cryptocurrencies and trades. this tables are in relationship: exchanges can have many cryptocurrencies and many trades as well. When i had only 1 relationship everything works fine. After i added trades table and i got many errors. I use Flask SQLAlchemy and Marshmallow

Exchange Model:

```
class ExchangeModel(db.Model):

__tablename__ = 'exchanges'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False, unique=True)
amount = db.Column(db.Float(precision=2), default=0)
currency = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
cryptocurrencies = db.relationship('CryptocurrencyModel', lazy="dynamic" )
trades = db.relationship('TradeModel')
```

Exchange schema

```
from ma import ma
from schemas.trade import TradeSchema
from schemas.cryptocurrency import CryptocurrencySchema
from models.trade import TradeModel
from models.cryptocurrency import CryptocurrencyModel
from models.exchange import ExchangeModel

class ExchangeSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
  trades = ma.Nested(TradeSchema, many=True)
  cryptocurrencies = ma.Nested(CryptocurrencySchema, many=True)
  class Meta:
     model = ExchangeModel
     dump_only = ("id","amount")
     load_instance = True
```

CryptocurrencyModel:

```
class CryptocurrencyModel(db.Model):

__tablename__ = 'cryptocurrencies'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
amount = db.Column(db.Float(precision=5), default=0)
rate = db.Column(db.Float(precision=5), nullable=False)
shortcut = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
exchange_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('exchanges.id'), nullable=False)
exchange = db.relationship('ExchangeModel')
```

CryptocurrencySchema:

```
from ma import ma
from models.cryptocurrency import CryptocurrencyModel
from models.exchange import ExchangeModel
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, validate

class CryptocurrencySchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
 class Meta:
    model = CryptocurrencyModel
    dump_only = ("id","amount")
    load_instance = True
    include_fk = True
shortcut = fields.Str(required=True, validate=[validate.Length(min=3)])
```

TradeModel:

```
class TradeModel(db.Model):

__tablename__ = 'trades'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
amount = db.Column(db.Float(precision=5), nullable=False)
currency_in = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
currency_out = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
created_date = 
db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True),server_default=db.func.current_timestamp())
exchange_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('exchanges.id'), nullable=False)
exchange = db.relationship('ExchangeModel')
```

Trade schema:

```
from ma import ma
from models.trade import TradeModel
from models.exchange import ExchangeModel

class TradeSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
 class Meta:
    model = TradeModel
    dump_only = ("id", "amount", 'created_date')
    load_instance = True
    include_fk = True
```

error is :

> InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class ExchangeModel->exchanges, expression 'CryptocurrencyModel' failed to locate a name ('CryptocurrencyModel'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'models.exchange.ExchangeModel'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.

Answer (score 0):

set

```py
ExchangeModel.cryptocurrencies = db.relationship('CryptocurrencyModel', lazy="dynamic" )
```

after you've declared `CryptocurrencyModel`:

```py
class CryptocurrencyModel(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'cryptocurrencies'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    amount = db.Column(db.Float(precision=5), default=0)
    rate = db.Column(db.Float(precision=5), nullable=False)
    shortcut = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    exchange_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('exchanges.id'), nullable=False)
    exchange = db.relationship('ExchangeModel')


ExchangeModel.cryptocurrencies = db.relationship('CryptocurrencyModel', lazy="dynamic" )
```

Comment: This was just a hint: you shouldn't use models that have not been declared at that point. You can add the relationships where the models are referenced later on, after the referenced model is declared.

Comment: i did it this way because i heard that you shouldt import model inside models .... so i dont know what is right :/